# Why isn't this even function's FFT real?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

So, in iPython, I run the following,

```
In [1]: from pylab import *;

In [2]: x = np.array([4.,3.,2.,1.,0.,1.,2.,3.,4.]);

In [3]: rfft(x)
Out[3]:
array([ 20.00000000+0.j        ,   7.79085937+2.83564091j,
        -0.21688142-0.18198512j,   0.50000000+0.8660254j ,
        -0.07397795-0.41954982j])
```

The variable `x` is an even function around the middle element in the array, but yet it's fft isn't entirely real as it should be. Why is that? How do I input an even function to numpy/scipy's fft function so it'll interpret it as the even function it's meant to be?

Comment: Were you expecting the origin to be at the middle of the array?

Comment: Are you sure that numpy uses the convention that the origin is the middle? It's common I believe for the origin to be the first element, try making your array [0, 1, 2, 1] and see if that works.

Comment: The N point cover a period of the frequency spectrum, without including the last frequency point which is the repeat of the first. So according to that convention you should use `np.array([4.,3.,2.,1.,0.,1.,2.,3.])` for a symmetric spectrum.

Comment: @SleuthEye that should be an answer and not a comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `N` samples cover a period of the signal without repeating samples (ie. without including the (N+1)<sup>st</sup> sample which is the same as the first one). To visualize this, you can match the samples with the corresponding symmetry candidate to get:

```
given signal        :              4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
periodic extension  : ...  1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 ...
symmetry            :              ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
                                   | | | | |_| | | | |
                                   | | | |_____| | | |
                                   | | |_________| | |
                                   | |_____________| |
                                   |_________________|
```

You can also verify this by plotting your signal with:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(18), np.append(x, x));
plt.plot(np.array([ 4.5, 4.5]), np.array([0,5]), 'r--');
plt.plot(np.array([ 9.0, 9.0]), np.array([0,5]), 'k--');
plt.plot(np.array([13.5,13.5]), np.array([0,5]), 'r--');
plt.axis([0, 18, 0, 5]);
plt.grid(True);
plt.show();
```

[image]

Where the dashed black line represent the period of your signal, and the red lines the midpoint along the period. As you can see, the signal is in fact not symmetric.

So according to that convention of not repeating the first sample, to get a symmetric signal you should define your signal as:

```
x = np.array([4.,3.,2.,1.,0.,1.,2.,3.])
```

which would produce the following real-valued (within numerical precision) frequency-domain sequence with the application of `rfft`:

> ```
> array([ 16.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,   6.82842712 -1.11022302e-15j,
>          0.00000000 -0.00000000e+00j,   1.17157288 -1.11022302e-15j,
>          0.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j])
> ```