# Python fft: Getting non-negligible imaginary component of Fourier transform of a real even function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I am creating a random even (symmetric) function from the centre of the array and checking its fft. I would expect it to be completely real, but it isn't and the imaginary part isn't negligible. Help with an explanation and solution. I checked other related posts, but can't find anything that helps me. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft, fftshift, ifftshift

def check_even(err):
    flipped_array = np.flip(err)
    return np.isclose(flipped_array, err).all()
    
def reflect(arr, neg=1):
    flipped_array = np.flip(arr[1:])
    even_array = np.append(flipped_array,arr)
    return even_array


x =  reflect(np.random.randn(100)) # my random function
dt = 1
fft = (2/len(x))*np.fft.fft(x)[:int(len(x)/2)]
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x))[:int(len(x)/2)]

print(f'We can see that the function is symmetric and even as this is true: {check_even(x)}')

subplots = 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplots, 1, figsize=(5*subplots, 5*subplots))
ax[0].plot(x, label='x')
ax[1].plot(freqs, fft.imag, label='imag fft')
ax[1].plot(freqs,fft.real, label='real fft')

ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
```

I was expecting negligible imaginary part of the Fourier transform but as can be seen, it isn't. Please help me out with a solution as well as possibly an explanation of why this is happening. Thanks!!
[image]

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465788/why-isnt-this-even-functions-fft-real) you shouldn't repeat the first sample to get a symmetric signal, ie: ```x =  np.random.randn(100)``` ```x = np.concatenate((x, x[::-1][:-1]))```

Comment: Use `rfft` instead of `fft` for real data